# How to insert old date into a table correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to insert an old date (01/01/1888) into a table within pl/sql code, but I only got value (01/01/1988) inserted.
What will be the correct way to insert this old date into a table?

```
declare
  p_date date;
  p_eventDate date;
  sql_str varchar2(2000);
begin
   select to_date('01-01-1888','dd-mm-yyyy') into p_eventDate from dual;

   p_date := add_months(sysdate,-60);

   if( p_eventDate < p_date)
   then
       sql_str := 'insert into test_date values (''' ||p_eventDate ||''')';
       sql_str := 'insert into test_date values (to_date(''' ||p_eventDate ||''',''dd-mm-yyyy''))';
   else
      sql_str := 'insert into test_date values (''' ||p_date ||''')';
   end if;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_str;

   commit;
  --dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
end;
```

When I check the table test_date, value 01/01/1988 and 01/01/0088 inserted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you code can be simplified.

If I understand well, you need to insert the minimum value from two variables; if so, you don't need dynamic SQL:

```
declare
  p_date date;
  p_eventDate date;
begin
   select to_date('01-01-1888','dd-mm-yyyy') into p_eventDate from dual;

   p_date := add_months(sysdate,-60);

   insert into test_date(d) values ( least(p_date, p_eventDate));

   commit;
end;
```

Keeping aside the dynamic SQL, the main issue in your code is that you are using dates in strings without casting them, thus relying on implicit conversions.

If, for some reason, you want to use dynamic SQL, a good way could be with bind variables, with something like:

```
...
sql_str := 'insert into test_date values (:1)';
execute immediate sql_str using someVariable;
...
```

If you want to keep the structure of your code, your SQL string should be:

```
sql_str := 'insert into test_date values ( to_date(''' || to_char(p_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') || ''', ''dd-mm-yyyy''))';
```

that is, you first have to cast the `date` variable to string, use it to concatenate your statement and then, in within your statement, cast back the string to a `date` type.

Comment: Sorry, I give you a bad example.Try to make it simple, I removed a lot of other codes from my procedure.I have to user the code 'sql_str := 'insert into test_date values (''' ||p_eventDate ||''')';' and the then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_str based on other conditions at the end of my procedure, and I cannot use 'execute immediate sql_str using someVariable;' to execute it. Thanks!

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Even simpler if you don't need the time component (i.e. time is 00:00:00), `'insert into test_date values (date ''' || to_char(p_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') || ''')'`.